# Can I use a subquery inside a case statement?

Tags: php, sql, case

Can I use a subquery inside a case statement? Is this possible?
Here's my code:

```
SELECT SUM(icd.discrepancy * (
    CASE WHEN $priceVal = 1 
    THEN SELECT i.dPrice FROM item_tb i 
    WHERE i.ID = icd.itemID
    ELSE SELECT p.dPrice FROM price_tb p 
    WHERE p.brID = '". $brID ."' AND p.itemID = icd.itemID
    END
)) as total
FROM invcountd_tb icd
WHERE icd.coID = '". $_SESSION['coID'] ."'
AND icd.invCounthID = '". $ID ."'
```

Comment: You will get syntax error due to incorrect escaping

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result, did it give an error, if so, what error...

Comment: Error on your query.
MYSQL ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT i.dPrice FROM item_tb i WHERE i.ID = icd.itemID ELSE SELEC' at line 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, Yes, you can have a subquery inside a Case statement.

Moreover, in your query above, I think you have another issue, which is that you are performing an aggregation on an expression containing a subquery, which gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you have to enclose the sub query in parentheses e.e:

```
CASE WHEN $priceVal = 1 THEN (SELECT i.dPrice FROM item_tb i WHERE i.ID = icd.itemID)                           
 ELSE (SELECT p.dPrice FROM price_tb p WHERE p.brID = '". $brID ."' AND p.itemID = icd.itemID)                           
 END
```

However you can still get errors if there are more than one row returned

Comment: True, but in his query, that case is inside the SUM, which would give him "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but your subqueries need to be in parentheses:

```
SELECT SUM(icd.discrepancy * (
                   CASE WHEN $priceVal = 1 THEN 
                            (SELECT i.dPrice FROM item_tb i WHERE i.ID = icd.itemID)
                        ELSE 
                            (SELECT p.dPrice FROM price_tb p WHERE p.brID = '". $brID ."' AND p.itemID = icd.itemID)
                        END
                    )) as total
FROM
    invcountd_tb icd
WHERE
    icd.coID = '". $_SESSION['coID'] ."'
AND
    icd.invCounthID = '". $ID ."'
```

I would however rewrite this as follows:

```
SELECT  SUM(icd.discrepancy * COALESCE(i.dPrice, p.dPrice))
FROM    invcountd_tb icd
        LEFT JOIN item_tb i 
            ON i.ID = icd.itemID
            AND $priceVal = 1
        LEFT JOIN price_tb p 
            ON p.brID = '". $brID ."' 
            AND p.itemID = icd.itemID
            AND $priceVal <> 1
WHERE   icd.coID = '". $_SESSION['coID'] ."'
AND     icd.invCounthID = '". $ID ."'
```

Your join conditions will do the case statement for you (i.e .only return `i.dPrice` if `$priceVal = 1`, and only return  `p.dPrice` if `$priceVal <> 1`. This avoids expensive subqueries which are poorly optimised in MySQL.

**[Simple Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92a35/1)**